# "Cover", "covering", or "is covered"?

Tags: verb-forms

Could you tell me which one is okay? I think **covers** or **is covered** might be right, but the answer key has **covering.**

> 1. The city of Montreal **covers** over 70 square miles.
> 2. The city of Montreal **is covered** over 70 square miles.
> 3. The city of Montreal **covering** over 70 square miles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I number your examples as followed to help me answering this question::

> (1) The city of Montreal **covers** over 70 square miles.
>   (2) The city of Montreal **is covered** over 70 square miles.
>   (3) The city of Montreal **covering** over 70 square miles.

Only the first two are sentences, (3) is not a sentence. Only (1) makes sense, (2) does not.

If you say: *a city is covered ...*, it will sound like the city is covered by something. For example, *The city is covered in water ...*, *The city is covered by snow ...*

To describe the size of the city, use: *The city **covers** [size or area description]*.